# Is there syntactic sugar to shorten the OnPropertyChanged construct?

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

Is there any way to shorten this copy-paste code?
The 26 words that follows contain actually just 4 piece of information: 
The visibility, the type, the name of the property and the behavior (which is the same for every property all over the world).

```
private PrinterInfo _currentConfiguration;

public PrinterInfo CurrentConfiguration
{
    get { return _currentConfiguration; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentConfiguration != value)
        {
            _currentConfiguration = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentConfiguration");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged